# Exit emacs client that runs inside emacs terminal buffer

Tags: term

Recently, I'd wanted to commit to my git repository from within emacs. Instead of running some git mode commands, I opened up a terminal buffer and run `git commit` inside. This works fine, except that the commit message editor is, of course, emacs. Out of habit, I tried to save-close the editor after inserting the commit message, but that closed my parent emacs...

Since I run emacs in client/server mode, I can simply reconnect and have all the buffers still open. But how do I close the child emacs (apart from killing it from within another terminal)?

In general, how do I send ctrl/meta to a program running in the terminal buffer?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but are you looking for `C-x #` (`server-edit`) ([see manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html#Invoking-emacsclient))?

Comment: Since you're already running in server mode, you can set your git to use emacsclient as your commit editor. The arrangement you're using sounds unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in `term` buffer in `char mode`, you have to escape `C-c`. So, if you're running a terminal Emacs instance inside the term buffer, running `save-buffers-kill-terminal` requires an extra `C-c`: `C-x C-c C-c`.

If you're running an Emacs instance in a `term` buffer in `line mode`, I don't think there's a direct way to kill the nested Emacs. You have to switch back to char mode first, via `C-c C-k`. Then you can call `C-x C-c C-c` as above.

That said, rather than starting an Emacs instance from your term buffer, you should call `emacsclient` instead. That will open up your file in a regular Emacs buffer in the current Emacs instance, without all the confusing nesting of Emacs-inside-term-inside-Emacs.

Comment: You are of course right, the whole thing happened out of old habit and wasn't intentional.